# How to query WAL generation rate by SQL Query in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Is there any SQL query to check the size of WAL historically?

I would like to check how much WAL information have been generated for 30 days by a SQL statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to do that.

What you *can* do is to regularly query the current log location with

```
SELECT pg_current_wal_lsn();
```

and keep the result in a log table.

Then, as vyegorov commented, you can calculate the difference in bytes between two WAL locations like this:

```
SELECT pg_wal_lsn_diff(lsn1, lsn2);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example. Then, any query to check transaction rate historically?

Comment: @Sigularity: Laurenz answered that right at the top: "*There is no direct way to do that*".

Comment: Why not to use `pg_xlog_location_diff` function to get difference between two LSN points?

Comment: In version >=10 the functions have been renamed to `pg_current_wal_lsn` and `pg_wal_lsn_diff` respectively

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I'd actually keep both versions in the answer, for history's sake.

Comment: @Pyrocks I considered that, but versions before 10 are already out of support, so I decided not to complicate the answer by mentioning historical parameters.